# DAX Group by and Sum

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax, measure

I am away that this question has already been asked, but the solutions I have found so far did not work.

I have a Dimension table with a business key, lets call it FacilityBK, and a number of bathrooms, BathroomCount. The BK is not the table's PK, so it often appears multiple times with the identical corresponding bathroom count. I want to get a DAX statement that is the SUM of BathroomCount for unique FacilityBK values.

```
FacilityBK = (1,1,2,2,3,3)
BathroomCount = (0,0,15,15,7,7)
```

The result should be 0+15+7 = 22, not 15+15+7+7 = 44

I have tried variations of the following query:

```
SUMX ( 
    SUMMARIZE( Dimension, Dimension[FacilityBK]),
    [BathroomCount]
)
```

However this yields me the sum of all BathroomCount values for every occurence (unique or non-unique) of FacilityBK. I also tried the `DISTINCT` function, creating a variable and passing that into `SUMX`, but it seems that for some reason it's not managing to select distinct values of FacilityBK.

The corresponding SQL code that gets me exactly the value I'm looking for looks like this:

```sql
select sum(dim.BathroomCount)
from
(
  select distinct(dim.FacilityBK), dim.BathroomCount
  from Dimension dim
) subquery
```

The result I get from the Dax is equivalent to removing the `distinct` function in the sql code.

As additional information I work on a SQL Server Database, SSMS, and Tabular Model 3. (the latter is where the DAX statements are written)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Measure = 
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Dimension',
        'Dimension'[FacilityBK],
        'Dimension'[BathroomCount]
    ),
    'Dimension'[BathroomCount]
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I had been stuck on that problem for a while now.